# Selecting the first two rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database like this :

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 123.78 |
| 12345 | 556.87 |
| 12345 | 1638.09 |
| 12345 | 133.44 |
| 56789 | 44 |
| 56789 | 434.2 |
| 56789 | 24.44 |

And i want my output to select the first two rows of each ID found and place the earliest value as new value and the oldest one as old value :

| ID | New Value | Old Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 123.78 | 556.87 |
| 56789 | 44 | 434.2 |

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variation on a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with filtering of the data:

```
out = (df
   .assign(col=lambda d: d.groupby('ID').cumcount())  # enumerate values
   .query('col < 2') # select top 2 per group
   .pivot(index='ID', columns='col', values='Value')  # reshape
   .set_axis(['New Value', 'Old Value'], axis=1).reset_index() # clean-up
)
```

Output:

```
      ID  New Value  Old Value
0  12345     123.78     556.87
1  56789      44.00     434.20
```

Comment: @Andrew you're welcome, you can generalize to more columns if needed by changing `col < 2` and passing more column names in `set_axis`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` and `nth`:

```
g = df.set_index("ID").groupby(level=0)
output = pd.concat([g.nth(0),g.nth(1)],axis=1).set_axis(["New Value", "Old Value"], axis=1).reset_index()

>>> output
      ID  New Value  Old Value
0  12345     123.78     556.87
1  56789      44.00     434.20
```

Comment: Which pandas version did you use? This actually doesn't work on pandas 2.1 as the output of `g.nth` is a DataFrame with the original index. You need to use `g = df.set_index('ID').groupby('ID')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [12345, 12345, 12345, 12345, 56789, 56789, 56789],
    "Value": [123.78, 556.87, 1638.09, 133.44, 44, 434.2, 24.44]
})


result = (df.set_index(['ID', df.groupby('ID').cumcount()])  # Enumerate values
             .unstack(fill_value=-1)
             .iloc[:, :2]  # Select first two columns
             .set_axis(['New Value', 'Old Value'], axis=1)  # Rename columns
             .reset_index()) 

"""
print(result)

     ID  New Value  Old Value
0  12345     123.78     556.87
1  56789      44.00     434.20
"""
```